# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm trying to add an unmanaged `dll` in my `c#` code. When I run the code, I get `dll` not found exception. What else is needed in my code to debug this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


    namespace FPGA_DLL
    {
         class Program
        {


             const string DllPath = "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\Dip\\ConsoleApplication1\\mcp2210_dll_um_x86.dll";


            /* API for getting access to the USB device */      
            [DllImport(DllPath, EntryPoint = "Mcp2210_GetConnectedDevCount", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int Mcp2210_GetConnectedDevCount(ushort vid, ushort pid);



            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const ushort MCP2210_VID = 0x04D8;   // VID for MCP2210
                const ushort MCP2210_PID = 0x00DE;   // PID for MCP2210

                int devCount = Mcp2210_GetConnectedDevCount(MCP2210_VID, MCP2210_PID);
                Console.WriteLine(devCount);

            }
        }
    }
```

Exception details
Unable to load `DLL`

> 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Dip\ConsoleApplication1\mcp2210_dll_um_x86.dll':
>   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

Comment: Either the DLL or a dependency, for instance the msvc runtime, cannot be found. As has been covered countless times here  before.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Make sure the DLL is where you say it is, and that it can find its dependencies

Comment: How are you running the exe? Try putting the dll in the same path you run it from. Or make sure it is in your PATH

Comment: @doctor Why don't you read the code?